# helper to modify the behaviour of an each in handlebarsJS

Tags: jquery, handlebars.js

My question is how can I access to the parameters "style" and "content" inside the template?, I modifed the helpers by creating another one (the base is teh same than in the official web), but I cannot access them.

**The template**

```
<div id=emoticons class="change_profile">
    {{#each all_avatars.images_male}}//this is an array['m1', 'm2, ...]'
        <img src="domain.com/{{this.content}}.png" style="{{this.style}}">
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

**The helper**

```
<script>
     Handlebars.registerHelper('each', function(icons_list) {
         var icons=[];
         var single={
             content:'',
             style:''
         }      
         for(var i=0, j=icons_list.length; i<j; i++) {
                    single.content = icons_list[i];
                    single.style='<something>';             
                    icons[i]=single; 
          }     
          return icons;
        });
</script>
```

**The result**

```
<div id=emoticons class="change_profile">

[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]                             

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Handlebars.js documentation (see [Simple Iterators](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html)), your helper is supposed to return a string that is directly rendered into the document. As you are returning an array (`icons`), it is converted to string and rendered as is.

The following declaration for the helper should give better results, especially considering that calling `options.fn(single)` should let Handlebars.js transform the template for you `img` tag into the proper image.

```
<script>
    Handlebars.registerHelper('each', function(icons_list, options) {
        var icons="";
        var single={ content:'', style:'' };

        for(var i=0, j=icons_list.length; i<j; i++) {
            single.content = icons_list[i];
            single.style='<something>';             
            icons += options.fn(single); 
        }       
        return icons;
    });
</script>
```

That being said, it's not a good idea to put this kind of logic into a helper named `each`, that can quickly become confusing. I'd rather use the same `each` as the one declared in the documentation and replace the template:

```
<div id=emoticons class="change_profile">
    {{#each all_avatars.images_male}}
        <img src="domain.com/{{this}}.png" style="<something>">
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

Comment: ok, I did that, and really was working without problems, perfect. My question now is, how can I return an array of objects in another different case?, I don't want to build the html content completely in the helper

Comment: Returning an array in a helper is out of the question. You can however declare your conversion code as a normal javascript function and use it to convert from an array to another. I'm not sure whether invoking it inline (e.g. `{{#each convert(all_avatars.images_male)}}`) would work though.